# wordpress doesn't return 404 if number in url

Tags: wordpress

i have a **worpress** website that works fine with 404 *not founding error* if u type

```
mydomain.com/blog/bla-bla
```

but there is a little strange thing if u type

```
mydomain.com/blog/1232424
```

or any number format . it wouldn't return  a 404 page and just load blog page like as always,

any hint would be help.
for more information i must say , i'm handling redirect page to 404 by a plugin and a costume 404 page that i've created.

Comment: What plugin you using for redirection?

Comment: @Earid [404 to 301](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404-to-301/) and [404 page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/)